# postgres stats on the new primary

Tags: postgresql

I have a RDS PostgreSQL v11.6 with primary and standby. On the primary, vacuum/analyze were running and  pg_stat_all_tables's last_vacuum/analyze/autovacuum/autoanalyze were having values when vacuum/analyze were run.

1. Switchover to Standby happened, now when I see pg_stat_all_tables (on the active primary which was standby earlier), the last vacuum/analyze columns are all nulls. Would primary-standby replication not replicate system tables? Is this how it behaves?
2. On the new primary, would the table have stats on them? (I do see pg_stats entries for the tables on new standby), are they reliable or do I need to gather stats and run vacuum after failover/switchover to standby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pg_stat_all_tables` is not an ordinary table, it is a view.  The majority of the view is based on functions, and those functions interact with the stats collector.  The stats collector uses its own files, not the ordinary database tables, for storage.  That data is not replicated, so is lost upon failover.

New activity on the promoted server will increment the activity counters, and eventually those will cause autovac to kick in.  If a table was "just about to be" vacuumed or analyzed on the master, it will lose that knowledge and restart from zero.  So tables could go up to twice as long between autovac/analyze kicking in.  This is generally not enough to cause substantial problems, but if your system was operating "close to the edge" to start with it might be a problem.

pg_stats is a view over pg_statisic, which is an ordinary table.  The data in it is replicated just like other tables.  So that data is not lost.  Because the activity counters are lost as described above, the statistics might grow more out of date than usual before being refreshed.

The free space map is not replicated.  So if your tables have free space in the middle where new rows can go, that space will not be used until the first vacuum is done after the fail over, to rebuild the map.  If you depend on this space re-use to prevent unacceptable bloat, then this might be reason enough to do a system-wide vacuum after a failover.